# Multithreading in python: how to hold the code inside the for loop and limit 20 threads in one go

Tags: python, multithreading, api, for-loop, concurrent-processing

I am working on a project for Algo trading using zerodha broker's API.
I am trying to do multithreading to save the costly operation of calling the API function for getting historical data for 50 stocks at a time and then apply my strategy on it for buy/sell.

Here is my code:

1. historical data function:

```
def historicData(token, start_dt, end_dt):
   data = pd.DataFrame( kite.historical_data( token,
                                              start_dt,
                                              end_dt,
                                              interval   = 'minute',
                                              continuous = False,
                                              oi         = False
                                              )
                        )
   # kite.historical_data() is the API call with limitation of 20 requests/sec
   return data.tail(5)
```

1. Strategy function:

```
def Strategy(token, script_name):
    start_dt = (datetime.now() - timedelta(3)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    end_dt = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    ScriptData = historicData(token, start_dt, end_dt)
    # perform operations on ScriptData
    print(token,script_name)
```

3. concurrent calling of the above function:

```
# concurrent code
from threading import Thread, Lock

start_dt = (datetime.now() - timedelta(3)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
end_dt = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

th_list = [None]*10

start = sleep.time()
for i in range(0,50,20):             # trying to send 20 request in a form of 20 threads in one go
    token_batch = tokens[i:i+20]     # data inside is ['123414','124124',...] total 50
    script_batch = scripts[i:i+20]   # data inside is ['RELIANCE','INFY',...] total 50
    j=0

    for stock_script in zip(token_batch,script_batch):
        th_list[j] = Thread( target = Strategy,
                             args   = ( stock_script[0],
                                        stock_script[1]
                                        )
                             )
        th_list[j].start()
        j+=1


end = sleep.time()
print('time is : ', end-start)
```

Now there are 2 issues I am unable to resolve after 2 days of trying many solutions online.

1. There's a bottleneck from the API server that it accepts 20 API calls per second and rejects if more are called. Total stocks in the list are 50 and I am trying to do is get data of 20 stocks at a time then get another 20 in the next and then remaining 10 in the third go. Total stocks list is gonna get big with 200 stocks soon that's why a serial execution is too costly for my strategy to work.
2. When running this function concurrently, there are too many threads created at once and API request exceeds... and `print('time is : ', end-start)` runs as soon as I run the 3rd cell.

So how do I block the code from leaving the inner for loop before all threads finish their execution.

and

Is my way correct to get 20 threads at the most per second? Should I place a `sleep(1)` somewhere?

Comment: `.join()` waits on a thread to finish. I would lean towards a thread pool from `concurrent.futures` for this.

Comment: What Python version?

Comment: python version is 3.8.2

Comment: @jordanm wont .join() make the execution similar to serial execution?